# Node AWS SDK start an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Using the node aws-sdk, I check the status of an instance, and want to let a user start it if it is dead, or kill it if it is alive.

I found that there is a method called `runinstances` but it seems like it creates new instances, and I want to revive a live one.

Is there a way using the node sdk to start/kill an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the logic to check the EC2 instance status using [describeInstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstanceStatus-property) method which will return the instance states (`InstanceState.Name`)

- pending
- running
- shutting-down
- terminated
- stopping
- stopped

Based on the current state (running or stopped) you can toggle the instance state using either of the following method.

- [startInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#startInstances-property)
- [stopInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#stopInstances-property)